# Resize APFS (encrypted) container

Tags: macos, partition, catalina, apfs

I am having trouble "attributing" some free space I have available on the *Files* partition to the volume which contains system files: an APFS encrypted container.

I would like to do this because I am no longer able to update some large application from within the App Store. I have already read some articles addressing the issue concerning resizing APFS containers but they still don't answer my question (or maybe I didn't clearly get the idea). I am running a Macbook Air under Catalina.

I put some screenshots that may give more useful information.

Reduce this volume to 90 GB:

[image: Reduce this volume to 90GB]

Increase the capacity of the container to 160 GB:

[image: Increase the capacity of the container to 160GB]

`diskutil list`:

[image: diskutil list]

`diskutil resizeVolume disk0s3 limits`:

[image: diskutil resizeVolume disk0s3 limits]

Comment: Please add the output of `diskutil resizeVolume disk0s3 limits`!

Comment: I added the output to the post - klanomath

Answer (score 1):

Simply resizing *Files* (disk0s3) and then expanding the container (disk0s2) while "shifting" disk0s3 won't work.

You have to take this path:

1. Resize disk0s3 with diskutil:

   ```
   diskutil resizeVolume disk0s3 40g
   ```
2. Create a fourth partition *Files2* (HFS+) with Disk Utility at the end of the disk
3. Copy all files from *Files* to *Files2*
4. Remove disk0s3 (*Files*) with Disk Utility
5. Rename *Files2* to *Files*
6. Expand disk0s2 (if not already done automatically in step 4):

   ```
   diskutil ap resizeContainer disk0s2 0
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, it worked! Also, step 5 was done automatically by Disk Utility.